# the table didn't separate completely on the pdf view

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, tcpdf, export-to-pdf

i want to have a separate table view in pdf page on my export (system) but the table is didn't separate fully on the view

i have tried to change my code but it didn't worked
controller code:

```
public function exportpdf(){
    $post=true;
    //webservice data pegawai
    $data['ws_user']='9Gf4H3pkLBjs';
    $url='https://pegawai.pcr.ac.id/services/get_pegawai_json';
    $data = array('ws_user' => '9Gf4H3pkLBjs');

    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);


    $datpeg=json_decode($result, True);

    //untuk data pegawai di array datpeg
    $data['tpl']=$datpeg['data'];

    $this->load->view("admin/exportpdf",$data);
}
```

[image]
view code:

I expected that the table is separate actually without any errors

Answer (score 0):

if you want the table row not getting split you should start your table with this tag.

```
<table nobr="true">
```

I hope this will fix your issue.